# magento some pages are blank

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.4

Suddenly on one of my stores some pages are blank:

www.theprinterdepo.com

click on my account
or on Cart

also search returns a blank page.

Some categories return the products, some other show the blank page.

The only thing I have done today is:
reindex
enabled cache and refreshed it.
changed the name of some categories.

I would like to know at least how to debug the problem, the Source of the blank pages is also empty.

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `var/log/error.log` and `var/log/system.log` in your Magento directory as well as your webserver's `error.log`